# Attach Existing Cloud Resource (ex: S3 Bucket) to a Pulumi Project

Tags: amazon-s3, pulumi

Firstly, I love Pulumi.

We're trying to propose Pulumi as a solution for a distributed architecture and it is going swimmingly. The uncertainty I have right now is if it's possible to attach an existing cloud resource to the Pulumi configuration.

There is already an S3 bucket existing with media, what I'm wondering is if it is possible to define the S3 bucket in our Pulumi config, *or* does Pulumi have to be the creator of the cloud resource before it can be managed by Pulumi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with a `get` function of a resource. In case of an S3 Bucket named "tpsReports-4f64efc" and a Lambda function "zipTpsReports-19d51dc", it would look like this:

```js
const tpsReports = aws.s3.Bucket.get("tpsReports", "tpsReports-4f64efc");
const zipFunc = aws.lambda.Function.get("zipTpsReports", "zipTpsReports-19d51dc");
```

When you run your Pulumi program, the status of these resources will say `read` instead of `create` or `update`.

If you want to go one step further and adopt an existing resource to be fully managed by Pulumi, [this blog post](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/adopting-existing-cloud-resources-into-pulumi/) documents the entire process.